# Trying to achieve a row column layout with batch

Tags: templating, layout

I tried to code an output in twig that should look the following ( 2 columns in one row), i figured that i will need the batch function

```
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
     </div>    
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
     </div>
```

My attempt is :

```
 {% for block in entry.content1|batch(2) %}
  <div class="row">
    {% for block in row %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

but it doesn't work like that, i looked it up in the twig documentation, the error from craft i get is "Variable "row" does not exist", so i tried changing it to {% for entry in block %} but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're getting your variable names mixed up. Something like this should work:

```
{% for row in entry.content1|batch(2) %}
<div class="row">
   {% for block in row %}
   <div class="col-sm-6">Content</div>
   {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I've changed the name of the first `block` to `row`.

Comment: No worries, I've done it myself :)